# Разбить строки на подстроки и поменять местами

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения, строки

После работы программы, возвращаются две строки формата такого:

```py
['Название предмета:"Предмет1"', 'Название предмета:"Предмет2"']  
['Мин. цена на данный момент:Цена1', 'Мин. цена на данный момент:Цена2']
```

Необходимо преобразовать их так, чтобы получилось что-то вроде:

```py
'Название предмета:"Предмет1"', Мин. цена на данный момент:Цена1'   
'Название предмета:"Предмет2", Мин. цена на данный момент:Цена2'
```

```py
name = re.sub(r'"name"', 'Название предмета', str(re.findall(r'\"name\":\".*', responseText)))
price = re.sub(r'"price"', 'Мин. цена на данный момент' , str(re.findall(r'\"price\":\S*', responseText)))
```

Это те самые строки, которые возвращаются после работы программы.
`responseText` — это небольшой набор данных, из которого я вычленяю подстроки `name` и `price`, он имеет вид примерно такой:

```py
[
  {
    "uid": "5ac84494-465a-424a-b36e-fe22869ba5ec",
    "bsgId": "59faff1d86f7746c51718c9c",
    "name": "Physical bitcoin (btc)",
    "shortName": "0.2BTC",
    "price": 139999,
    "avg24hPrice": 139868,
    "avg7daysPrice": 139056,
    "updated": "2020-03-03T07:31:54.939Z",
    "slots": 1,
    "diff24h": 0.09,
    "diff7days": 0.68,
  }
]
```

Comment: `responseText` символ в символ, как в вопросе? Если бы там были запятые, то можно было бы распарсить как `JSON`.

Comment: Похоже, Что Это [Проблема XY](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/710/339283)

Comment: покажите как вы получаете эти строки - похоже проблема в неправильном использовании полученного ответа

Comment: nomnoms12, если смотреть со стороны формата, то да. Строки вытаскиваются именно из такого формата, однако сырые данные действительно имеют запятые вместо переноса строки, это я их заменил split`oм. Расскажите пожалуйста подробнее про JSON.

Comment: @MikkelOntberg покажите сырые данные, а потом расскажем

Comment: исправил в вопросе

Comment: Ну например `print(['Название предмета: {name}, мин.цена: {price}'.format(**x) for x in json.loads(responseText)])`

Comment: Спасибо, все как надо. Не пойму только как коммент ответом на вопрос пометить

Comment: @andreymal Не желаете оформить как ответ?

Comment: @nomnoms12 нет.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете распарсить Ваш ответ с помощью модуля `json`.

***Пример:***

```py
import json


def main():
    responseText = r'[{"uid":"5ac84494-465a-424a-b36e-fe22869ba5ec","bsgId":"59faff1d86f7746c51718c9c","name":"Physical bitcoin (btc)","shortName":"0.2BTC","price":139999,"avg24hPrice":139868,"avg7daysPrice":139056,"updated":"2020-03-03T07:31:54.939Z","slots":1,"diff24h":0.09,"diff7days":0.68}]'
    d = json.loads(responseText)

    for x in d:
        name = x['name']
        price = x['price']
        print(f'Название предмета: "{name}", мин. цена на данный момент: {price}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

***stdout:***

```py
Название предмета: "Physical bitcoin (btc)", мин. цена на данный момент: 139999
```